# Indian visa with Bangladeshi origins

Tags: visas, india, uk-citizens, visa-extensions, bangladesh

I am a UK citizen with a UK passport, my father was from Bangladesh.  My Mother is English and  she and my father divorced when I was 3 and so I never knew him.  However because he was from Bangladesh I can only obtain a 3 month visa for India, does anyone know why, and if I can add any information with my application to help me get a 6 month visa.

Comment: Do you have dual citizenship, as in are you a citizen of Bangladesh as well?

Answer (score 1):

[This might help you](http://boi.gov.in/content/information-foreigners-possessing-entry-x-visa-2), it is an Indian govt site about visa extension.

Comment: When reading the conditions, I am not sure it matches the question (i.e. the parent shouldn't be a Bangladesh citizen).